# Multitenant Ruby Application using Subdomain and no subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multi-tenant

I've developed an application that is using PostgreSQL with a multi schema to achieve the multitenant side of the application. The tenant is checked via Subdomain, but I am trying to find a way to be able to still use the main domain as the registration point and administrative backend for myself.

Below is my application controller, where I believe the check tenant is happening.

I followed the railscast from here http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql?view=comments

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  before_filter :mailer_set_url_options

  def mailer_set_url_options
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
  end

  around_filter :scope_current_tenant

private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
 helper_method :current_user

  def current_tenant
    @current_tenant ||= Tenant.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
  end
  helper_method :current_tenant

  def scope_current_tenant(&block)
    current_tenant.scope_schema("public", &block)
  end
end
```

The other issue I am noticing is through devise. It appears because of the multitenant and defining the helper current_user in the application controller is playing finicky with the session from devise, any ideas?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution? @richard

Comment: @scanales I haven't found one as of yet, the project was put on hold and I moved on to the next one. If I come back to it I will definitely add my solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a tenant for your main domain (for eg. visitors) and current_tenant therefore is set to nil in that case, you cannot call current_tenant.scope_schema, but I believe you can do something like this:

```
 def current_tenant
   # Select tenant based on a user and set it to nil if no user:
   @current_tenant ||= current_user.tenant unless current_user.nil?
 end
 helper_method :current_tenant

 def scope_current_tenant(&block)
   if current_tenant.nil?
      scope_visitor_schema
      yield
   else
     current_tenant.scope_schema("public", &block)
   end
 end  

 def scope_visitor_schema()
   original_search_path = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path  = 'public'
 ensure
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = original_search_path
 end
```

In this example tenant is selected based on the user rather than a subdomain, but the approach is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution and forgot to post it, but your comment made me remember. This is what I'm doing when scoping the current client:

Basically I make the `current_id` something invalid, in this case `"admin"`, when the subdomain equals `"admin"`, and don't set the `current_id` when the subdomain is `www`, or blank (which I would use for the main page.

Hope this helps

```
 def scope_current_client
  case  request.subdomain
    when /^admin$/
        Client.current_id = "admin"
    when /^www$|^$/

    else
        Client.current_id = current_client.id
  end
  yield
  ensure
    Client.current_id = nil         
end
```